# PHP HTML5 compatible MP4 video using FFMPEG

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, html5-video, internet-explorer-10

Hi I am using FFMPEG to convert the uploaded video with PHP.

```
echo "conversion exercise started...<br/><br/>";

/* looping through all files in the directory */
if ($handle = opendir('assets/uploaded_videos')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        /* filtering the desired extensions */
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && in_array(substr($entry, strrpos($entry, '.')), array(".wmv", ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".flv", ".ogg", ".mp4")))
        {
            $filename = substr($entry, 0, strrpos($entry, '.'));

            //$command = "ffmpeg -i assets/uploaded_videos/$entry -vcodec libx264 assetss/videos/$filename.mp4";

            $command = "ffmpeg -i assets/uploaded_videos/$entry -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libfaac files/videos/$filename.mp4";

            echo $command."<br />";

            shell_exec($command."> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

I have embedded the player in view file like this:

```
<video width="350" poster="<?php echo $first_video['thumb_path'];?>" controls>
    <source src="<?php echo $first_video['video_path']; ?>" />
    <span id="silverlight_player_for_fallback"></span>
</video>
```

Now, when I run in IE10, the player gives me **invalid source** error. I am having this issue with both `libx264` and `mpeg4` MP4 codecs.

Any ideas whats going wrong?

## Update

Following Ian's direction, I finally get it working. I have used **baseline-level3** profile with **libx264**. You can provide extra parameters but I guess profile is the key! I experimented couple of profiles and observed that all HTML5 videos on vimeo and youtube use this baseline L3 profile.

Anyone struggling with MP4 can consider the following command for conversion:

```
/* following command converted all my uploaded *.wmv files to mp4 */
$command = "ffmpeg -i files/uploaded_videos/$entry -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3 files/videos/$filename.mp4";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tested the generated MP4 file in other browsers (that support MP4) such as Chrome and Safari? The first step is to ensure that the file actually plays.

You could also save the generated MP4 and try and drag it into Chrome/Safari and then IE10 (if the other browser works) to see if it can play. This way you can attempt to see if it's the encoding that's the issue.

There are many different flavours (known as [profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles)) of MP4, not all can play in browsers.

Comment: It doesn't work on any browser; IE9, IE10, Safari and Chrome. In general Chrome doesn't show error in player if the source is invalid. No activity on seek-bar indicates there is something wrong. Anyway, which profiles are supported for HTML5? The wikipedia page you referred doesn't explain that.

Comment: Ok, so it's the encoding that's not working. The base profile is usually the best I think, but this answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119797/ffmpeg-settings-for-converting-to-mp4-and-ogg-for-html5-video) might help with using FFMPEG to create a compatible MP4 video.

Comment: Thanks Ian. It worked! I have updated my post with the exact solution. I'll take yours as an answer. I used `baseline level 3` profile with `libx264` codec.