# HTML5 video won't play in IE9

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9

URL: http://carolpolis.com/#media

HTML

```
<video width="auto" height="200px" poster="images/WithCourage.jpg" controls>
<source src="media/WithCourage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="media/WithCourage.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="media/WithCourage.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

.htaccess

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf
```

Doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

The video's play perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but in IE9 I only see the "poster" image and no media controls. It seems to know that they're videos but when I right click them and press "Play" nothing happens.

Thanks so much in advance for any help!
Meredith

Comment: Fix your html first: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fcarolpolis.com%2f#media

Comment: I did, thanks http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcarolpolis.com%2F

Comment: Great, now we can look for the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of your mp4 video is not correct.

Based on the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798978/php-html5-compatible-mp4-video-using-ffmpeg) I converted one of the videos on your site to use a baseline (3) encoding profile and that made the video work on an html page in IE10.

Comment: I did not want to use PHP to convert the videos so I used the HTML5 Video Converter here http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software.htm and replaced the .mp4 files with the new ones which I'm assuming had the correct encoding profile to work with IE9. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The person in that question was using ffmpeg http://www.ffmpeg.org/ which is what dvdvideosoft is probably using behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute URL like:

```
<video width="auto" height="200px" poster="images/WithCourage.jpg" preload controls>
<source src="http://carolpolis.com/media/WithCourage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://carolpolis.com/media/WithCourage.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://carolpolis.com/media/WithCourage.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`

Comment: Tried it but no luck. Thank you for trying!

Comment: Added the update to the <head> section and the preload property but the video's still don't seem to play in IE9. The audio files are fine though, it's just the videos. Thanks again for the attempt!

Answer (score 0):

After wasting on this problem a lot of time.I found the problem(with fiddler2) that returned content type is wrong. I tried to fix it with web.config but nothing helped .So I wrote specific action for video file and problem was solved

```
public ActionResult GetVideoFile(string id = "")
{
    string dir = Server.MapPath("/Content/MyVideoFiles");
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, id);
    if ((System.IO.File.Exists(path))) {
        return File(path, "video/mp4");
    }
    return null;
}
```